# Add function dynamically as an attribute

Tags: javascript

```
var objects = [
    { name: "test1", data: "asdf" }, 
    { name: "test2", data: "aa" }, 
    { name: "test3", data: "" }
];
for (var element in objects) {
    var node = document.createElement("p");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(objects[element].name);
    node.setAttribute("id", objects[element].name)
    node.draggable = true;
    node.ondragstart = "drag(event)";
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("leftUI").appendChild(node);
}
```

When I inspect element, this is what I see:

```
<p id="test1" draggable="true">test1</p>
<p id="test2" draggable="true">test2</p>
<p id="test3" draggable="true">test3</p>
```

I need to see ondragstart="drag(event)" thing in my code:

```
<p id="test1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">test1</p>
<p id="test2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">test2</p>
<p id="test3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">test3</p>
```

How do I do it?

`addEventListener` doesn't work, it fires on page load.

Comment: If `addEventListener` is firing on page load that means you're using it incorrectly. You should post that code so we can help with that, as `addEventListener` is the method you should be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `setAttribute`:

```
node.setAttriubte("ondragstart", "drag(event)");
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace your `node.ondragstart = "drag(event)";` with `node.ondragstart = drag`

When working with javascript you actually have to assign the function and not just a string representing the function.

Answer (score 0):

You have some answers that tell you how to do what you asked for, but based on your statement about [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) causing the event to fire on page load, it sounds like you are trying to work around a problem caused by using `addEventListener` incorrectly. My guess is you are using it something like this: `node.addEventListener('dragstart', drag(event))` or some similar form that causes the function to execute at the time the listener is added.

The proper usage is of the form `node.addEventListener('dragstart', drag)`. Note that you should not include any parameters or parentheses; only the function name should be listed.